# How to run php file in webroot of cakephp project

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to run php file which is placed in webroot folder of cakephp 2.5 project.
while running that i am getting error given below
[image]

Here nghome is the folder which is placed in webroot of the project and i want to execute a database.php file which is in webroot/nghome/database.php but while executing that file i am getting error where it says nghome controller is not found.

any help or suggestion will be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes Jonas, I have solved this please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this working by updating .htaccess file under webroot folder with below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make any changes in htaccess or anywhere else, simply creating a php file `database.php` inside webroot you can access it from browser like `example.com/database.php`

```
file path - app/webroot/filename.php
access from browser - example.com/filename.php

file path - app/webroot/somedir/filename.php
access from browser - example.com/somedir/filename.php

file path - app/webroot/somedir/subdir/filename.php
access from browser - example.com/somedir/subdir/filename.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and i have tried this way but it is not working, any other way to achieve this.

Comment: try it at /app/webroot/file.php - you may need to do some htaccess magic to make it work straight from /file.php

Answer (score 0):

check your .htaccess file working or not inside webroot folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This line  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is responsible for executing existing files.
And also request full path including file name `nghome/database.php`

Comment: dear yakng, i have tried your code in .htaccess file of webroot but i didn't work, i can access nghome folder in webroot but after that when i try to access database.php it drop me in error page [Error: NghomeController could not be found.],

Answer (score 0):

You can run your php file from webroot by putting your file in nghome folder in webroot and hit the URL with file name.

http://www.example.com/nghome/filename.php